# Remove parent element from variable but keep children

Tags: jquery

I have a small problem. I have a small span with some buttons in it.

```
<span class="buttons">
      <button type="button" id="pc_0" class="btn btn-outline-dark" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off" title="IP adresa : 192.168.1.204">DESKTOP-I22M3QS</button>
      <button type="button" id="pc_1" class="btn btn-outline-dark" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off" title="IP adresa : 192.168.1.204">DESKTOP-I22M3QS</button>
</span>
```

First, i have a AJAX get request stored inside a data variable

```
> $.get('Home/Index', function (data) {}
```

Inside data i have a whole page . After that I  withdraw whole element ".buttons" to a variable

```
var buttons = $(data).find('.buttons')[0];
```

And now comes the problem. I want to remove span  and keep only buttons. But i really cant get hold of a span "buttons".

What I am aiming for is this :

> 

```
<button type="button" id="pc_0" class="btn btn-outline-dark" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off" title="IP adresa : 192.168.1.204">DESKTOP-I22M3QS</button>
<button type="button" id="pc_1" class="btn btn-outline-dark" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off" title="IP adresa : 192.168.1.204">DESKTOP-I22M3QS</button>
```

I tried several things but i always gets undefined. Can somebody help me to solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the line:

```
var buttons = $(data).find('.buttons')[0];
```

to:

```
var buttons = $(data).find('.buttons button');
```

but it would be a jQuery object.

Comment: Thanks but its not working. First i need to work with variable buttons , you are working but element buttons. And second i tried your solution with variable buttons but it deletes children and keep parent, so exactly oposite

Comment: I've just changed my answer, have another look.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery `unwrap()`: https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

This is exactly the function you seek.